# Expo BarCodeScanner undefined is not an object (evaluating 'Object.keys(viewManagersMetadata)')

Tags: javascript, react-native, camera, expo, barcode-scanner

I am trying to implement the expo-barcode-scanner, when I import the package in my component I am getting this error 'undefined is not an object (evaluating 'Object.keys(viewManagersMetadata)')', I am not familiar with this package... is there something I am missing here ?

I try to downgrade my expo version from 45 to 44, 43 and 42... I saw youtube videos with people using this package with older version, but it still gives me this error...

I tested only on the AndroidEmulator.

Error on Android Emulator ->

[image]

ScannBarcodeScreen.js

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { View, Text, TouchableOpacity, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { BarCodeScanner } from 'expo-barcode-scanner';


const ScannBarcodeScreen = () => {

    const [hasPermission, setHasPermission] = useState(null);
    const [scanned, setScanned] = useState(false);
  
    useEffect(() => {
      (async () => {
        const { status } = await BarCodeScanner.requestPermissionsAsync();
        setHasPermission(status === 'granted');
      })();
    }, []);
  
    const handleBarCodeScanned = ({ type, data }) => {
      setScanned(true);
      alert(`Bar code with type ${type} and data ${data} has been scanned!`);
    };
  
    if (hasPermission === null) {
      return <Text>Requesting for camera permission</Text>;
    }
    if (hasPermission === false) {
      return <Text>No access to camera</Text>;
    }
  
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <BarCodeScanner
          onBarCodeScanned={scanned ? undefined : handleBarCodeScanned}
          style={StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject}
        />
        {scanned && <Button title={'Tap to Scan Again'} onPress={() => setScanned(false)} />}
      </View>
    );
  }
    
  const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
      flex: 1,
    },
    camera: {
      flex: 1,
    },
    buttonContainer: {
      flex: 1,
      backgroundColor: 'transparent',
      flexDirection: 'row',
      margin: 20,
    },
    button: {
      flex: 0.1,
      alignSelf: 'flex-end',
      alignItems: 'center',
    },
    text: {
      fontSize: 18,
      color: 'white',
    },
  });

export default ScannBarcodeScreen;
```

package.json ( dependencies )

```
"dependencies": {
    "@eva-design/eva": "^2.1.1",
    "@expo-google-fonts/libre-barcode-128": "^0.2.2",
    "@expo-google-fonts/montserrat": "^0.2.2",
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^13.0.0",
    "@react-native-community/checkbox": "^0.5.9",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^14.0.1",
    "@react-native-firebase/auth": "^14.0.1",
    "@react-native-firebase/firestore": "^14.0.1",
    "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^14.0.1",
    "@react-native-firebase/storage": "^14.0.1",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.0.9",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.6",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.2.5",
    "@stripe/stripe-react-native": "0.6.1",
    "@ui-kitten/components": "^5.1.1",
    "@ui-kitten/eva-icons": "^5.1.1",
    "big.js": "^6.1.1",
    "eas-cli": "^0.50.0",
    "expo": "^45.0.0",
    "expo-app-loading": "~2.0.0",
    "expo-barcode-scanner": "~11.3.0",
    "expo-camera": "~12.2.0",
    "expo-dev-client": "~0.9.6",
    "expo-fast-image": "^1.1.3",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.15.1",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.3.0",
    "expo-updates": "~0.13.1",
    "jsbarcode": "^3.11.5",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "react-native": "0.68.2",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.2.1",
    "react-native-image-slider-box": "^1.1.14",
    "react-native-modal": "^13.0.0",
    "react-native-paper": "^4.11.2",
    "react-native-phone-number-input": "^2.1.0",
    "react-native-qrcode-svg": "^6.1.2",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~2.8.0",
    "react-native-redash": "^16.2.3",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.2.4",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.11.1",
    "react-native-select-dropdown": "^1.13.0",
    "react-native-svg": "12.3.0",
    "react-native-swipe-modal-up-down": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-toast-message": "^2.1.1",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.0.0",
    "react-native-view-slider": "^1.1.1",
    "react-native-web": "0.17.7",
    "referral-codes": "^2.0.1",
    "tailwind-react-native-classnames": "^1.5.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@types/react": "~17.0.21"
  }
```

Comment: installing `expo install expo-modules-core` fixed the issue. https://github.com/unimodules/react-native-unimodules/issues/142#issuecomment-1141401312